# Issue logging in from second computer

Tags: login

I'm fairly new to Wordpress, so please bear with me on this.

I've been having issues logging into my Wordpress admin panel on a second computer. I originally set up WP on my work computer and all works fine there. However, I tried to log in with my personal computer and was denied. After logging into WP successfully (blue side panel), I navigated to the WP Admin link at the bottom. When I click it, it takes me to a second log in screen (never saw this on my work computer). When I type my credentials in (correct credentials), it says that my email and/or password is incorrect.

Attempted the following solutions, but nothing worked...

- Attempted to reset password but never received a password reset email.
- Cleared all cookies and cache.
- Attempted to log in from both Safari AND Chrome.

Again, everything is fine on my work computer. I'm able to log in to my account (only once) and access the Admin Panel at will. My personal computer only lets me onto the initial account page (blue side panel).

What is going on?

Comment: Can you provide a link to your site? Would help in addressing the issue. Also is this a production or development site?

Answer (score 0):

I sought help from WP directly as well and they responding with the solution very quickly (super impressed).

> A special login setting was disabled for your site (it's called single sign on, or SSO). I flipped the switch and enabled it again. You should now be all good to log into the WP-Admin dashboard now.

I can confirm that I am now able to log in on multiple computers.